# Why .equals method is failing on two same value objects?

Tags: java, unit-testing, equals

I have created a value object `MarketVO` and two instances of this value object have same elements and same value for each element.

My value object class is:

```
public class MarketVO {

    private double floatAmt;
    private Date marketDate;
    private long marketCap;
}
```

Here are the values:

returnedData:

```
FloatAmt: 247657.5418618201, MarketCap: 5249164,
MarketDate: 2011-07-29 00:00:00.0
```

expectedData:

```
FloatAmt: 247657.5418618201, MarketCap: 5249164, 
MarketDate: 2011-07-29 00:00:00.0
```

Now in my unit test class, I want to assert that my returned and expected type is same containing same value in same order so am doing something like

`assertTrue(returnedData.equals(expectedData))`, now this is returning `false` value but if I do

```
assertEquals(testObject.getfloatAmt(), testObject2.getfloatAmt());
assertEquals(testObject.getmarketCap(), testObject2.getmarketCap());
assertEquals(testObject.getmarketDate(), testObject2.getmarketDate());
```

this test passes and so am not sure as to why `.equals` method is not working in here? Any suggestions?

**Update:** I want to put emphasize here that we are using this for doing ***Unit Testing***.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default implementation of [`.equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) compares object references, not object content.

You probably want to override the equals (and hashCode) methods. Something like this:

```
public class MarketVO {

    private double floatAmt;
    private Date marketDate;
    private long marketCap;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof MarketVO))
            return false;
        MarketVO other = (MarketVO) o;
        return other.floatAmt == floatAmt &&
               other.marketDate.equals(marketDate) &&
               other.marketCap == marketCap;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: so now is there a way to compare two object contains without comparing on `getFuncs` because my vo has many properties and it's very hard to have assert on `getFunc` for 10 or 15 fields, any suggestions.

Comment: You could probably do some hack with reflection, or use a `Map` for your attributes, but overriding `equals` like above is probably the most common solution.

Comment: hmm...am just trying to see if there is any other way out, now in my test class `MarketVO` is not the only VO but i am having 3 different VO's in there and so coupling `marketVO` in equal method is something that I am not comfortable with.

Comment: in your code why are doing compare with `==` for floatAmt and marketCap and with `.equals` on marketDate?

Comment: Because you may compare primitives with ==

Comment: @aioobe: now `.equals` method fail here because am getting marketDate as null value and so null.equls(null) fails that is valid but other.marketDate==marketDate passes and so am thinking should i compare using == for marketDate? Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, then you need to take care of `null` case specially. `other.marketDate==marketDate` won't do, since again, you're comparing references, not "object content".

Answer (score 3):

Use rather the org.apache.commons library which gives you sophisticated ways implement those valuable methods well. The same library also contains ToStringBuilder which is very handy too.

Maven dependency => commons-lang3 (org.apache.commons)

```
class WhatEver{
...

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, false);
   }


   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj, false);
   }

...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `equals` method doesn't work as you didn't override it for your required behaviour. The default behaviour on `Object` (which your class inherits from) is to compare references. Two different instances have different references, thus the `equals` fails.

Comment: Override, not overload in this case. (Overloading it would have worked too, I guess, but it would be odd to overload without overriding.)

Comment: can you give an example of this?

Comment: @Jon - Can you provide and example keeping unit test scenario in mind?

Comment: @Rachel: No, I was only commenting on the use of terminology. I don't have time to write anything else right now.

Answer (score 2):

By default `.equals()` checks **identity** and not **equality**. Change and add this code to your class

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        MarketVO marketVO = (MarketVO) o;

        if(Double.compare(marketVO.floatAmt, floatAmt) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if(marketCap != marketVO.marketCap) {
            return false;
        }
        if(marketDate != null ? !marketDate.equals(marketVO.marketDate) : marketVO.marketDate != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        long temp;
        temp = floatAmt != +0.0d ? Double.doubleToLongBits(floatAmt) : 0L;
        result = (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (marketDate != null ? marketDate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (int) (marketCap ^ (marketCap >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) annotation [`@EqualsAndHashcode`](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html), it really helps to avoid bugs with `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

It creates equals and hashCode methods using all non-static non-transient fields by default, but you can specify other behaviors like excluding some fields:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"fieldsThat", "dontMather"})
```

or including only some fields:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"onlyFields", "thatMather"})
```

Answer (score 0):

the hashes are different because they are different instances

Comment: hashes and hashcode have nothing to do with this. They make sense only in hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely the default behaviour is to compare object's addresses in memory (true if the references point to the exactly same object (address) in memory). So override these methods the get the required behaviour.