# Why are these two instances not `equal()`?

Tags: java, equals, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why .equals method is failing on two same value objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877947/why-equals-method-is-failing-on-two-same-value-objects)

This is really simple but I'm obviously missing something pretty big here.

```
Cat cat1 = new Cat("bob");
Cat cat2 = new Cat("bob");
System.out.println(cat1 == cat2); 
//false since these references point to diferent objects
System.out.println(cat1.equals(cat2));
//returns false also??
```

`Cat` is just a simple class that only has a name.

What is going on here, how does `equals()` work? I was under the impression that it compared all the fields of the object. It seems that is not the case.

Do I need to overide it for all my classes?

Comment: I bet only @john skeet can get true with both above statements. ;-)

Comment: @michael , aah that was a joke,  i think you should refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: Perhaps something with where the objects are being referenced  in memory...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling ^ there are many jon skeet facts, refer to link above. Enjoy :-)

Comment: in simple words, Java does not support operator overloading and hence  == simply does not work on objects

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

`java.lang.Object` provides very basic implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()`. In particular, they don't go around reflecting on the type of the instance, which would (1) be dreadfully slow, and (2) carry a significant risk of comparing fields that you for various reasons don't want to compare in an equality comparison.

If you want equals() and hashCode() to actually be useful for comparing value equality (rather than reference equality which `==` does), you'll need to implement both within your own type.

Note that it's not enough to implement just `equals()`; while technically that will "work", it has the potential to lead to all kinds of weirdness. The simple rule of thumb is: *neither or both, but never only one*. And they must work on the same fields; if `equals()` says two instances are equal, then calling `hashCode()` on both *must* return the same value (also see the [`hashCode()` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)).

It's also usually a good idea to override `toString()` with code to provide a meaningful description of the object in question. While not strictly needed, you only need to hit your head against this once in the debugger to realize the value. (Thanks @JonTaylor for mentioning this highly useful, related tidbit.)

And it's .NET that calls it `GetHashCode()`, while Java uses only `hashCode()` as the function name...

Comment: While you're at it too, I tend to override the `toString()` method to give some meaningful description of the object.

Comment: Good point, @JonTaylor. Going to add a mention of that too.

Comment: I cant believe i havent run into this problem before. From what i can see two objects are equal if their states ie their fields are equal. In that case an overiden equals method should just compare all the relavent fields correct?

Comment: Yes and if you use an IDE like eclipse it can do it for you. (Right Click -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()...)

Comment: @Luke1111 Java has no way of knowing which of your fields are relevant for object value equality. Some might hold internal state or for that matter values that have no impact on whether two instances should be considered "equal". Plus reflection is **expensive**.

Comment: @Luke1111 - One reason that the default `equals` is object identity (instead of equality of field values) is the latter is actually very difficult to get right, and basically impossible to get right in a general way (which would be required if it were default behavior). See, for example, ["How to Write an Equality Method in Java"](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html). In particular, there are significant issues that must be considered (and basically dealt with on a case-by-case basis) when a class can have subclasses.

Comment: @TedHopp And `java.lang.Object` without subclasses would be... quite useless.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Heh, yeah. However, I was thinking about subclasses of the user's class (e.g., `Cat` might have subclasses `WildCat`, `DomesticCat`, `FeralCat`, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `equals` inside your `Cat` class. Default equals compares objects on references.

```
class Cat {
private String name;

public Cat(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Cat))
        return false;
    Cat c = (Cat) obj;
    return this.name == null ? false : this.name.equals(c.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.name == null ? 31 : this.name.hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cat Name :" + name;
}
}
```

---

References

- [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)
- [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: That is perfect. But i believe providing cooked up code hampers learning process,

Comment: @MukulGoel Agree but some times its better to have reference of the perfect code since these methods will be required each and every time

Answer (score 0):

The `equals()` provided by java.lang.object compares, simply speaking, a unique identifier for the object, though not entirely accurate you can think of it as a memory location, so it will only be true if you compare an object with itself (i.e. two references to the same object in memory)

You need to implement your own equals() method in your Cat class:

```
class Cat
{  
   String name;

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Cat other)
   {
      if (this.name.equals(other.name))
          return true;
      return false;
   }
}
```

It would be wise to override `hashCode()` also, unless this is just a very basic application for homework or something. Also `toString()` can be useful to override as well.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: or `return this.name.equals(other.name);`

Comment: What if name is `null`? Or `other` is null?

Comment: Your overridden method should have a parameter of type **Object** not **Cat**, you must check using instanceof if it is of type **Cat**.  Furthermore you need to check if the object is null before accessing its parameters or methods.

Comment: this is just an example to follow. he can do the work of nullchecking :-)  @rees yeah, if it uses _only_ the name string he can just return the evaluation of the string comparison

Comment: Jon that would effectively remove the type safety. If it accepts type Cat, you don't need to do instanceof - static, strong typing ensure you only give this argument an object of type Cat or a subclass of Cat. Allowing any object to compare with cat is effectively meaningless, no?

Comment: if it accepts type `Cat` then you are not overriding, simply creating a method called equals which happens to have the same name as a method in a superclass.

Comment: damn. good point, it is overloading not overriding. at execution time, though, this is the method that will execute if a Cat object is passed as the argument... this raises some design questions about Java

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `==`  compare references and `java.lang.Object.equals()` translates to `this==o` thus return same as `==` in your case

In the case above you are using new operator to create two different objects hence both return false.

If you want `.equals()` to work as you are expecting, then override the`equals()` in your `Cat` class.

Comment: Actually, `Object.equals(Object o)` simply returns `this == o`. There's no "unique identifier" that's any different than what `==` uses: the object reference. Your answer is worded in a way that suggests that there is some difference.

Comment: @tedHopp yea you are right, its worded that way. i'l correct n update it for better readability

Answer (score 0):

From [[Java Doc]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, ***this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object*** (x == y has the value true).

Without overriding the equals() method, the objects are different
Hence

```
 System.out.println(cat1.equals(cat2)); // is false
```